# How cast value from SharedPrefereces to FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences

I want to design the custom turn-off/on for push notification using SharedPreferences.

How I can get value (true or false) from SharedPreferences in FirebaseMessagingService?

Both my options don’t work:

1. To get value directly from SharedPrefences but getPreferences isnt work inside FMS.
2. To pass value from activity to FirebaseMessagingService. But how?

Maybe there is third option which will work. Please help me.

**Below is my code file of FirebaseMessagingService**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

private val CURRENT_PUSH = "currentPush"
private var sPref: SharedPreferences? = null

override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

        if (remoteMessage!!.data != null)
            sendNotification(remoteMessage)
}

private fun sendNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    val data = remoteMessage.data

    val title = data["title"]
    val content = data["content"]

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1234"

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                "SA Notification",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)

        notificationChannel.description = "SA channel notification"
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
        notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 1000, 500, 1000)
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }


    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sa_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setContentInfo("Breaking")

    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
}

override fun onNewToken(s: String?) {
    Log.i(C.T, "NEW_TOKEN" + s!!)
}

private fun loadCurrentPushNotification(): Boolean { //to read the status push notification from SharedPreferences
    sPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) //this is not working
    return sPref!!.getBoolean(CURRENT_PUSH, true)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sPref = getSharedPreferences(CONTEXT)
```

Unsure what `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` so you may have to replace with application context

then

```
 return sPref!!.getBoolean(CURRENT_PUSH, true)
```

Comment: it began to work but not right. The result shows the value which specified as default in **getBoolean(CURRENT_PUSH, true)**. Properly value in SharedPreferences ignored.

Comment: Sorry it was late last night, edited answer should work

Comment: first argument requires String

Comment: edited, you only needed to change to `getSharedPreferences()` ?

Comment: Unfortunately don't works. getSharedPreferences requires two arguments (String name, int mode). What can be name and mode there?

Comment: Name is the name of the shared pref and int mode is the default value you set